# Kusto - Splunk to Kusto Query conversion for "max(_time) as time by jobid | sort -time"

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am working on Splunk to Kusto Dashboard conversion . Could you please tell me how do I convert the below Splunk query to Kusto

I understood the filter for the result but I am stuck where it is summarizing with max(_time) as time by jobid | sort -time

`| stats count(eval(result=="failed")) as failed count(eval(result=="succeess" OR result=="progress")) as succeeded max(_time) as time by jobid | sort -time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be this:

```
| summarize failed = countif(result=="failed"), 
            succeeded = countif(result=="succeess" or result=="progress"),
            ['time'] = max(_time) by jobid 
| sort by ['time'] desc
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me . The same method I would like to use for the ifelse condition . I am unable to count the result with the Kusto Query . 

Splunk Query
```| eval result=if(Match(Status,"Success|Passed"), "succeess","failed")```

Kusto Query
```| extend result = case(Status in ("Success", "PassedOnRetry"), "succeeded", "failed")```

Comment: or if I use the below Kusto Query

```| summarize success = countif(Status in ("Success", "PassedOnRetry")), total = count()
| extend failure = total - success```

how do I calculate the time like the below
  ['time'] = max(_time) by jobid 
| sort by ['time'] desc

Comment: I am able to complete the Query . refer below.

```| summarize succeeded = countif(Status=="Success" or Status=="Passed"),
            failure = countif(Status!="Success" or Status!="Passed")```

Comment: Looks like you figured it out, well done!